# Generate a list of the week/year according ISO 8601

Tags: date, datetime, groovy, week-number

I try to generate a list of days with their [week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) (defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates)) accordingly :

```
mydate='2012-12-25 02:26:55.983'
for (i=1;i<365;i++)
{
  mydateAsDate=new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.S',mydate)+i;
  println 'Week ' + mydateAsDate.format('w') + ' => ' + mydateAsDate.format('dd.MM.yyyy');
}
```

This works but I would like to get the year also like this:

```
Week 1-2013
```

I can't figure out which year information I should take.

Any idea?

Comment: I suggest you stay away from the deprecated methods in Date... if you *possibly* can, use Joda Time instead. It'll make all of this a lot easier.

Comment: FYI, your string format does not follow the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) standard. Should be: `2013-W01`.

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet said, I'd recommend using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

If you do, the following should fix your issues:

```
mydate= new DateTime(2012,12,25)
yearLater = myDate.plusYears(1)
while(myDate < yearLater){
  println "Week ${myDate.weekOfWeekyear} - ${myDate.year}"
  myDate = myDate.plusDays(1)
}
```

Comment: ok, i'll try JodaTime but the fact is that I work on a environment where I should not be able to add new libraries :-/

Comment: If you need rational to help justify the addition of the library, you could maybe use this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/introducing-new-date-and-time

The Joda Time library is essentially becoming the new standard Java library with Java 8

Comment: Good answer, but I suggest passing a [DateTimeZone](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) instance to the constructor of [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html). The definition of a day depends on time zone. Specify or else get whatever the current JVM's default.

Comment: One fix needed to example code. The `weekOfWeekyear` method returns a [`DateTime.Property`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.Property.html) object. To directly access the week number as an `int`, call [`getWeekOfWeekyear`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#getWeekOfWeekyear()). (Note the 'get' prefix.) Ditto with `year`; call [`getYear`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#getYear()).

Comment: Last thought… If you want to get the ISO 8601 format for a week, use this: `ISODateTimeFormat.weekyearWeek().print( dateTime )` to generate a string like `2014-W09`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand, but you mean like:

```
String startDateString = '2012-12-25 02:26:55.983'
Date startDate = Date.parse( 'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.S', startDateString )
(1..364).each { i ->
    println( (startDate++).format( "dd.MM.yyyy : 'Week' w'-'yyyy" ) )
}
```

Comment: this is almost that, but I cannot use the year of the current date. The code above returns : http://pastebin.com/0jk6jjjD ; this should be 1-2013 for 30.12.2012 and 31.12.2012

Answer (score 0):

I got it : SimpleDateFormat delivers the right week year information when using the YYYY format

thus this is only available in java 1.7

thanks for your responses though !

cheers